# datetime keyerror in json API data

Tags: json, python-3.5

Using Python 3.5, I'm trying return data from the Todoist REST api, which is in JSON format.

> > [{'id': 2577166691, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577166691', 'completed': False, 'order': 2, 'content': 'soon', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'due': {'recurring': False, 'date': '2018-04-01', 'timezone': 'UTC+10:00', 'datetime': '2018-04-01T10:00:00Z', 'string': 'Mar 31 2019'}, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577166849, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577166849', 'completed': False, 'order': 3, 'content': 'To City +1', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'due': {'recurring': False, 'date': '2018-03-31', 'string': 'Mar 31'}, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577225965, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577225965', 'completed': False, 'order': 4, 'content': 'To City +2', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577974095, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577974095', 'completed': False, 'order': 5, 'content': 'To City +3', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577974970, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577974970', 'completed': False, 'order': 6, 'content': 'Next train from City', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577975012, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577975012', 'completed': False, 'order': 7, 'content': 'From City +1', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577975101, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577975101', 'completed': False, 'order': 8, 'content': 'From City +2', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577975145, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577975145', 'completed': False, 'order': 9, 'content': 'From City +3', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}]

I can correctly obtain data for all items, eg

`print(json_tasks[0]['id']`

> > 2577166691

And it also works for

`print(json_tasks[0]['due']['recurring'])`

> > False

`print(json_tasks[0]['due']['date'])`

> > 2018-04-01

But:

`print(json_tasks[0]['due']['datetime'])`

> > 'KeyError: 'datetime'

I have tried a number of things but I'm stumped. What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to recognise 'datetime' as a key?

Answer (score 0):

The code below, when I ran it, printed out `2018-04-01T10:00:00Z`.

`json_tasks = [{'id': 2577166691, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577166691', 'completed': False, 'order': 2, 'content': 'soon', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'due': {'recurring': False, 'date': '2018-04-01', 'timezone': 'UTC+10:00', 'datetime': '2018-04-01T10:00:00Z', 'string': 'Mar 31 2019'}, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577166849, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577166849', 'completed': False, 'order': 3, 'content': 'To City +1', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'due': {'recurring': False, 'date': '2018-03-31', 'string': 'Mar 31'}, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577225965, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577225965', 'completed': False, 'order': 4, 'content': 'To City +2', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577974095, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577974095', 'completed': False, 'order': 5, 'content': 'To City +3', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577974970, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577974970', 'completed': False, 'order': 6, 'content': 'Next train from City', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577975012, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577975012', 'completed': False, 'order': 7, 'content': 'From City +1', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577975101, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577975101', 'completed': False, 'order': 8, 'content': 'From City +2', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}, {'id': 2577975145, 'project_id': 2181643136, 'url': 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2577975145', 'completed': False, 'order': 9, 'content': 'From City +3', 'priority': 1, 'comment_count': 0, 'indent': 1}]`

`print(json_tasks[0]['due']['datetime'])`